# User relation to group and company MongoMapper

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper, database

I have need to create a system where a user can login with a user account where a user is a member of a group like admin or editor. Also a user is a member of a company. in both cases of groups and company's they can have multiple users but user can be only a member of one company and multiple groups.

The relations that i can get out of this is that a group has many users, company has many users, user has one company, user has many groups.

but my problem then how do i create this with ruby and mongoMapper? i have look at the documentation and other sources but did not find a good solution or explanation on how to use or set this up.

If anyone have a better way of doing it also welcome.

these are the current classes i have written.

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :username, String
  key :password, String
  key :name, String

  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :company
end


class Group
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :group_id, Integer
  key :name, String
  key :accesLevel, Integer

  many :user
end


class Company 
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String

  many :user
end
```

Comment: This looks relational, so why Mongo?

Comment: the be able to expand the application in the future without needing to change complete database. also this is only a small part of the complete system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more google searching i have found a solution.

first i made the user class look like this:

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :username, String
  key :password, String
  key :name, String
  key :companyID
  key :groupID
  timestamps!

end
```

then the group and company class like this:

```
class Company 
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
  timestamps!

end



 class Group
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
  key :accesLevel, Integer
  timestamps!

end
```

With these classes in place i changed my controller to first create a company and then a group these could also be loaded but for the ease of testing it was not necessary to do this  so that i didn't need to write the code for this.

```
company = Company.new
company.name = "comp"

group = Group.new
group.name = "admin"

user = User.new
user.name = "user1"
user.username = "user1"
user.password = "passuser1"

user.groupID = group.id
user.companyID = company.id

db_config = YAML::load(File.open('./dbconfig.yml'))

MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new(db_config['hostname'])
MongoMapper.database = db_config['name']

company.save
group.save
user.save
```